# "No rule to make target" with % in Makefile Error

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I am writing my first Makefile. In it, I want all files that have been updated in a folder called `FOLDER/assets` to be copied to `FOLDER/export_bin/application/assets`. I've been using https://makefiletutorial.com/ as a reference.

Here's the code I wrote for it:

```
build_game:
    $(MAKE) $(export_folder)/application/assets/%
    ...

$(export_folder)/application/assets/%: ../assets/%
    cp $@ $<
```

I get the error:

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'debug/application/assets/%'.  Stop.
```

How should I do this instead?

Comment: make is very picky, are you using tabs or spaces for your indentation? It needs to be tabs

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! What is your rationale behind the `$(MAKE)` line in the `build_game` rule? I am thinking that you'd probably rather want to put the target of the `$(MAKE)` up after the `build_game:`. As for the second rule ... my years of intuition tell me this is the wrong way to go about things, but I can't right now articulate why, so I will think about it.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Just checked, and it is all tabs!

Comment: @Vercingatorix I just wanted to be able to call another section of the file, and that was the only way I knew how to do it. Are you suggesting there's another way to do it if I put the targets above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
base := FOLDER
export_folder := $(base)/export_bin
import_folder := $(base)/assets
input_files := $(wildcard $(import_folder)/*)
# See https://makefiletutorial.com/#string-substitution
output_files := $(patsubst $(import_folder)/%,$(export_folder)/application/assets/%,$(input_files))

# See https://makefiletutorial.com/#phony
.PHONY: build_game
build_game: $(output_files)

$(export_folder)/application/assets/%: $(import_folder)/%
    cp $< $@
```

The first few lines set up the directories we will be using. The key line is the `input_files` assignment calling `$(wildcard)`. (This is a [GNU extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html).)  The tutorial you went to doesn't appear to cover this feature.

Then we construct the output file list by substituting the import paths for the output path. The `.PHONY:` pseudo-target indicates that `build_game` is not intended to be a real file; otherwise `make` can get confused. We make the `build_game` target dependent on the output files; this triggers the rules for making the output files at the end. Finally we have the output file rule; it's essentially the same as what you used, except you swapped the `$<` and `$@` and used a relative path, which might work but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Thanks so much! I had a feeling that the % had to be split up into multiple lines.

Comment: My pleasure. You can thank me by choosing this as the Accepted Answer (check mark icon to the left of the answer).

Answer (score 0):

```makefile
asset_files := %(notdir $(wildcard ../assets))
target_asset_files := $(addprefix $(export_folder)/application/assets/,$(asset_files))

build_game : $(target_asset_files)

$(export_folder)/application/assets/%: ../assets/%
    cp $@ $<
```

`build_game` is dependent on all the asset files, which will get copied over via the pattern rule if they are out of date.

One sharp stick here is that if you delete a file in the source directory (`../assets/`), it would not be deleted in the target directory, so your target directory will not necessarily be in sync with the source...   If you need the two to be in sync, there's other ways to do that.

------ EDIT ---------

to use rsync, you would do something to this effect:

```makefile
asset_src := ../assets
asset_trg := $(export_folder)/application/assets

build_game : rsync_sentinel

rsync_sentinel: $(wildcard $(asset_src)/*)
    rsync -a --delete $(asset_src)/ $(asset_trg)
    touch $@
```

Here, the sentinel file is a dummy file whos timestamp represents the last time it did a copy.   If any of the files inside `../assets` is newer than the sentinel, it will use rsync to copy any necessary files over, and then update the timestamp of the sentinel.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your response! I'll process more what you wrote in a bit, but I was curious what ways you'd recommend files in the target directory to be deleted. Maybe a directory junction instead of what I'm doing here?

Comment: I could also just write a little python script I call to remove files for me.

Comment: You could just make your target directory a link to the source directory for example.  Otherwise, you could use [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) with a sentinel target instead of the pattern rule.

Comment: rsync sounds perfect. Thanks!